# binding string format from code-behind?

Tags: wpf, binding, string-formatting

Please, can some body tell me how to get my double value formatted like "0.0" from code-behind, like this:

```
Binding b = new Binding(DoubleValue);
b.StringFormat = "????";
```

In xaml it works just like that "0.0"...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about this?

```
b.StringFormat = "{0:F1}";
```

---

See the documentation of [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) and also [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) and [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

---

EDIT: Just to make clear how a binding would be created and assigned (to the `Text` property of an imaginary TextBlock named `textBlock`) in code:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public double DoubleValue { get; set; }
}

...

var viewModel = new ViewModel
{
    DoubleValue = Math.PI
};

var binding = new Binding
{
    Source = viewModel,
    Path = new PropertyPath("DoubleValue"),
    StringFormat = "{0:F1}"
};

textBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
```

Alternatively:

```
var binding = new Binding
{
    Path = new PropertyPath("DoubleValue"),
    StringFormat = "{0:F1}"
};

textBlock.DataContext = viewModel;
textBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I saw all those articles. It doesn't work, i don't know why... Can you try it in real case?

Comment: Ok, it's a textBox in a user control bound to ObservableCollection item.Value, binding works by itself and there is output, but StringFormat doesn't influence on it. And I've noticed that I was wrong about value type it's float, does it make a difference?

Comment: Why don't you post the relevant code parts? At least the relevant part of the item class, i.e. the DoubleValue property declaration. Also the code where you actually apply the binding would be interesting. Otherwise, it's all guesswork. And what exactly is `DoubleValue` in your sample code?

Comment: As i said DoubleValue is actually not a double but a float value of property in a view model, sorry but it would be tons of code for you to get clear what is happening.. But this place is pretty simple, I'm pretty sure that there are no other bindings, so only this binding works, and even StringFormat works, for example if i make it "{0:F1}asdas" the output is "12.12321asdas" but it is not formatting  the value..

Comment: I can reproduce a StringFormat of "{0:F1}asdas" creating an output of "12.12321asdas", just by changing the property type from `float` to `string`. You're binding is wrong somehow, that's why I strongly suggest to post more code. Not all, but the relevant parts.

Comment: Clemens, thank you very much!!!!!! I'm VERY SORRY for this post generally. But you helped me a lot with your last comment!) The most problem is that my part of work no this current project is developing  ui. I've just contacted to developer who did models and view models and it seems that the DoubleValue is typeof string. Thanks a lot again.