# WPF StringFormat in Binding doesn't work in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, string-formatting, datatemplate

I am trying to create a DataTemplate programmarically 100% in the codebehind. Everything works perfectly, except the StringFormat on the text binding in the textblocks doesn't work.

Normally in xaml, I would accomplish this like so:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding MyProperty, StringFormat=0.0} />
```

so I assumed I could just set the StringFormat property of the Binding object, which I did. I verified that it gets set correctly, and it does, but my view still doesn't reflect the formatting. Why?

Here is an excerpt from my code: a function that creates a DataTemplate dynamically for me. Literally everything else works perfectly, from setting the binding path to the ivalue converters, and everything. Just not the string format.

```
string propertyName = "myPropertyName";
FrameworkElementFactory textBlock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));

// the property I want is owned by myObject, which is a property of the datacontext
string bindingString = String.Format("myObject[{0}]", propertyName); 
Binding binding = new Binding(bindingString)
{
    Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
    Converter = (IValueConverter)Application.Current.FindResource("InvalidValuesConverter"),
    StringFormat = "{0:F1}" // <-- Here is where I specify the stringFormat. I've also tried "0.0"
};

textBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
```

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is your best friend. Because as of now everything seems to be [probably correct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769529/binding-string-format-from-code-behind), but without actual types and format strings used and a huge pile of unrelated code it is difficult to be sure.

Comment: Edited to strip out unnecessary code

Comment: The Binding in code behind has a Converter, therefore it ignores the StringFormat.

Comment: @Clemens I tested and found that not to be the case.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Does your converter return a string?

Comment: @Clemens Yes, it returns a string. I checked MSDN and it says the value goes through the converter first, which sounds like you get both. I just changed my converter to return an integer literal. The binding applies the StringFormat either way.

Comment: "[If you set the Converter and StringFormat properties, the converter is applied to the data value first, and then the StringFormat is applied](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Anchor_1)"

Comment: So my converter returns a string. Its purpose is to turn NaNs into empty strings so it doesn't mess up my view. I commented out the converter, and the stringformat worked perfectly.

Comment: I think @Ed Plunkett is right about that quote, but it is trying to StringFormat the string returned by the converter, which doesn't work. It's not a double at that point, it has turned into a string. Gonna test that theory now.

Comment: @user3685285 That sounds right to me. If I use `"N={0:#}"` as a StringFormat, it converts double `3.5` to `"N=3"`, but string `"3.5"` becomes `"N=3.5"` -- that is to say, it does apply the StringFormat in either case, but the numeric formatting fails on strings.

Comment: Since `Convert` returns `object`, there's no reason you can't return empty string for `NaN` and a double if it's a valid double.

Comment: Yep. We have solved the case. Thanks for your help guys. Ed, if you put an answer I'll mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like what you're seeing is that the `StringFormat` is being applied, but it doesn't do numeric formatting on the string values your converter is returning. Since the particular format you're using has nothing in it but numeric formatting, in effect the converter + `StringFormat` processing is a no-op in the non-NaN case. The quickest way to test this assumption is to give it a format like `N={0:#}`, which I did. It formatted decimal `3.5` as `"N=4"` and string `"3.5"` as `"N=3.5"`.

Naturally, [values are passed through the converter before they're formatted.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Anchor_1)

Since the only purpose of your converter to substitute an empty string for `Double.NaN`, I'd advise that your converter only convert to string in the `NaN` case, and otherwise return the double value as-is. `Convert` returns `object` so that's no problem.

For simplicity, the code below assumes that you can count on `value` always being `double`.

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (double.IsNaN((double)value)) 
            ? "" 
            : value;
    }
```